# Riemann Integration of greatest integer function on x^2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

How to show $$ [x^2] +\mid x-1 \mid $$ is Riemann Integrable in [0,2] ?

After splitting into 3 intervals

$$[0,1],[{1,\sqrt 2 }], [{\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3 }], [{\sqrt 3,2] }$$

I will explain how I proceeded my doubt is with greatest integer function part, 
after splitting into 3 intervals

$$[0,1],[{1,\sqrt 2 }], [{\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3 }], [{\sqrt 3,2] }$$

In the interval $$[0,1]$$ Supremum of function is 1 and Infimum is 0.

In the interval $$[{1,\sqrt 2 }]$$ Supremum of function is 2 and Infimum is 1.

In the interval $$[{\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3 }]$$ Supremum of function is 3 and Infimum is 2.

Now U(P,f) = $$ 1(1-0)+2(\sqrt 2-1)+ 3(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)+4(2-\sqrt 3)                 $$

and L(P,f) = $$ 0(1-0)+1(\sqrt 2-1)+ 2(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)+3(2-\sqrt 3)                 $$
and they are different values.

Comment: Do you know that a function is Riemann integrable if it is bounded and has a finite number of points where it's not continuous?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that theorem. But how to make L(P,f) and U(P,f) equal here, then only it is Riemann integrable, right?  Is there anything wrong in the way I have calculated the Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following method:

Since the function $ [x^2]  $ is discontinuous at $1,\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3  $ in the interval [0,2], 
we partition the interval as follows:

x<sub>0</sub>($=0$), x1 , x2 .... xi, y<sub>0</sub>($=1$), y1 , y2.... yi,z<sub>0</sub> (=$\sqrt 2$),z1 , z2.... zi, k<sub>0</sub> (=$\sqrt 3$),k1 , k2.... ki,m<sub>0</sub>$(=2)$

Now U(P,f)= 0*$\Sigma$x<sub>i</sub> + 1*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +1*$\Sigma$y<sub>i</sub> + 2*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) + 2*$\Sigma$z<sub>i</sub> +3*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>)+ 3*$\Sigma$k<sub>i</sub> + 4*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

=$0+1*(\sqrt2-1)+2*(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)+3*(2-\sqrt3)+$1*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +2*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) +3*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>) + 4*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

Take
        $\epsilon$ = 1*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +2*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) +3*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>) + 4*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

Now L(P,f)= 0*$\Sigma$x<sub>i</sub> + 0*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +1*$\Sigma$y<sub>i</sub> + 1*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) + 2*$\Sigma$z<sub>i</sub> +2*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>)+ 3*$\Sigma$k<sub>i</sub> + 3*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

=$0+1*(\sqrt2-1)+2*(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)+3*(2-\sqrt3)+$  1*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) +  +2*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>)+  3*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

Now taking U(P,f) - L(P,f) <  $\epsilon$

Hence $ [x^2]  $ is Riemann Integrable in [0,2]

Comment: (y0-xi) etc.. are very small quantities since it is partitioned like that.